# Rotation speed of Progress M-27M

Tags: orbital-mechanics, artificial-satellite, low-earth-orbit, attitude

On launch date, when first reports of Progress M-27M mishap were received, it was reported (and seen in the released onboard video) that the ship was rotating around its barycenter at an approximate speed of 12 RPM. Later, in its final orbits before reentry, earth-based sightings reported variations in apparent magnitude with an approximate period of 1.8 seconds, which indicates a revolving speed of some 33 RPM. What could be the reason for this increment in rotational speed?

Comment: Welcome to [space.se] @Claudio!

Comment: Would you be OK with a bit of speculation in answers? Initial telemetry data suggested that it could have sprung a leak in one of its propellant tanks during separation. Another possible explanation is strong atmospheric tides on days prior to reentry. My personal favorite is however that ground observed variations in apparent magnitude being nearly three times the initially reported rotation speed could be largely due to the two solar panels Progress uses on each side of the craft. So you'd get two flares on one single rotation of the craft around its axes with ~ 3.6 s period, or 17 rpm.

Comment: Thanks for your views, @TildalWave. Certainly if there were any constant leak, that wold be sufficient to gradually accelerate its rotation movement. Regarding the solar panels, I didn't know that they were already unfolded when the ship lost contact with its base.
At least we're talking about plain, straightforward causes for the acceleration, and not some obscure energy transfer between translation and rotation, which was my initial concern...

Comment: @Claudio Solar panels were deployed, that information was in the last complete telemetry received on the ground. Two KURS antennas probably never deployed though. There was also a lot of speculation about _odd orbital decay_ in the tracking community, as it _didn't appear natural_, despite strong solar activity and could only partially be attributed to Progress fragmentation. I guess we'll only know for sure when the final report of the incident investigation comes in (expected on May 22, but that might slip), if they'll even be bothered by its later decay in it (kinda doubt it).

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Atmospheric Drag.

Long answer: A spacecraft which is in the high atmosphere can start to spin, and the speed of that spin can increase. It is essentially like a windmill. This really only affects spacecraft in the realm of 200-300 km or so, that aren't build to withstand such changes, and thus aren't in full control. It is entirely possible that this was purely a result of atmospheric drag.